# How to get Do It… after you've completed the story mode?

Tags: achievements, dance-central-3

The Do It... achievement requires you to get five stars performing the 70's craze song while in story mode. Somehow, even when playing on Easy, I managed to only get four stars (I got every other craze song achievements though).

Now since the craze song is not a complete song, it doesn't actually appear in the song list after you've finished the story mode.

My question is: how do I unlock this achievement now that I have finished the story mode? Is there a way to reset the story mode progress or is the partial song hidden somewhere that I don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song you need to 5-star for this achievement is "The Hustle".  It should be available for selection normally.

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dance_Central_3):

> All songs are unlocked from the start except Tan-Step, which is
>   unlocked after leveling up.  After completion of story mode, all of
>   the songs, including Tan-Step, become part of the Master Quest.

Comment: This is a very late reply (sorry). I can now confirm the correctness of your answer. Thanks!